# Nemo te alius pari potestate saepius profuit (Apul. Florida 9)

Tags: ablative, apuleius

Would you consider *te* to be dependent from *pari* ("with a position as powerful as yours") or *saepius* ("more often than you")?

*par* can be constructed with simple ablative, but rarely and more common is *cum* + abl. As for saepius, it just sounds strange, i would expect *seapius profuit **quam (tu)***.

Answer (score 3):

I would actually suggest a third solution: alius + ablative (*nemo alius te: nobody else than you*).

Alius + ablative is recorded by the Oxford Latin Dictionary:

> "nec quicquam aliud libertate communi quaesisse"
>   "quodsi accusator alius Seiano foret"

The position of *te* between *nemo* and *alius* could also be a further argument for this interpretation.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for an interesting answer! I didn't know that *alius* can go with ablative like that.